# Want to see SOAP-Traffic with a JAX-WS Client

Tags: jax-ws

I have JAXWS-Client with following lines of code to connect to server:

```
final QName serviceName = new QName(Namespace.SERVICE, "FileService");
service = new FileService(new URL("http://localhost:8059/WS/FileService?wsdl"), serviceName);
file_service = service.getSOAP11();
```

My problem is, that I'd like to see the soap-traffic via eclipse TCP/IP-Monitor.
So I set the monitor in the middle between client and server. But all I can see is the wsdl in the first response. I think the reason is, that the client reads the endpoint address from the received wsdl (with port 8060) and use it for further traffic. But that is the real endpoint and not the faked (8059) for the TCP/IP Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the soap traffic on the client you have to set the system property:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

Then you get the soap-traffic at standard out.